# Can/should I mix EF Core versions/implementations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are looking to set up a new SQL database to consolidate a various tables of data that are presently scattered in a few different places. The thinking is to take advantage of this opportunity to use EF Core 5/.NET 5 to define and create the database and for future development work.

There are a number of existing or planned in-house tools that will need to interact with the database, and consequently will be updated as needed. However, one piece of vendor-supplied software we also use is essentially locked to .NET Framework - it is integrated by consuming custom-written libraries via COM interop, but only those written for .NET Framework/Standard 2.0.

This piece of software would only need to perform relatively simple queries, inserts and updates. Is it practical/sensible to use a special implementation EF Core 3.1 that reverse engineers the same database generated and maintained separately elsewhere using EF Core 5?

Comment: Are you asking "can I use many different ORMs to access the same database?" - if so, "yes"

Comment: That's encouraging, but is there anything to be said about whether one should go that route? Is it one of those cases that basically boils down to "it depends"?

Comment: From what you say you don't really seem to have a choice? Do your .net 5 app and just accept that this custom locked piece of COM whatever software will go it's own way. It won't matter

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having different components use different versions of EF other than that you cannot centralize your domain model. Designing long-lasting systems involves finding a balance between the risk of "Lava Flow", and "If it ain't broken". For existing .Net Framework implementations I'd lean towards using EF6 rather than EF Core 3.1 as it's more feature-functional.